# HTTPS post - what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: delphi, post, https, stream, connection

I'm making requests to the webaddress to get XML files throught the HTTPS connection. But this connection works like 50%. In most cases it fails. Usual error is "socket error #10060". Or "Error connecting with SSL. EOF was observed that violates the protocol". What I'm doing wrong?

```
function SendRequest(parameters: string): IXMLDocument;
var
   sPostData: TStringList;
   sHttpSocket: TIdHTTP;
   sshSocketHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
   resStream: TStringStream;
   xDoc: IXMLDocument;

   begin
      sPostData := TStringList.Create;

      try
         sPostData.Add('add some parameter to post' + '&');
         sPostData.Add('add some parameter to post' + '&');
         sPostData.Add('add some parameter to post' + '&');
         sPostData.Add(parameters);

         sHttpSocket := TIdHTTP.Create;
         sshSocketHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
         sHttpSocket.IOHandler := sshSocketHandler;

         sHttpSocket.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
         sHttpSocket.Request.Method := 'POST';

         resStream := TStringStream.Create;
         sHttpSocket.Post(Self.sUrl, sPostData, resStream);

         xDoc := CreateXMLDoc;
         xDoc.LoadFromStream(resStream);

         Result := xDoc;

         resStream.Free;
         sHttpSocket.Free;
         sshSocketHandler.Free;
         sPostData.Free;
      except on E: Exception do
      begin
         TCommon.ErrorLog('errorLog.txt', DateTimeToStr(Now) + ' ' + E.Message);
      end
      end;
    end;
```

Maybe I can do this in another way, that works like 100%, when internet connection is available?

Regards,
evilone

Comment: How old is your version of Indy? If it's the one that came with Delphi then get the latest from SVN. How old is your OpenSSL library? Is it v0.9.x or 1.x.x?

Comment: I don't know exactly. That came along with Delphi XE. OpenSSL library is version 1.0.0.3

Comment: what do you think about StreamSec and SecureBridge? This HTTP connection is important for my application. So, it's better than no external DLL-s here - only native code.

Comment: Did you write the server as well?  Is this a FORM being posted?

Comment: @evilone The best option is get away from Indy and use the HTTP client, be it ours or the one from /n software or other vendor. The reason is that Indy is a moving target (they break compatibility between builds, not talking about versions), and you can't guarantee that IOHandler will work right, especially the years-old and unsupported StreamSec.

Comment: That's a wee bit harsh. Indy has been difficult in the past, true, but it's working fine for us now. Synapse too is a good library and, apparently, has good OpenSSL support - but I haven't tried that part of it. I'm sure the Eldos stuff is good too - and you'll get tech support - but you will have to pay.

Comment: @Darian No this is desktop application making HTTPS POST's to the server. And it's not a form where I'm posting. Just a service giving ma XML responses.

@shunty If I build my app with Synapse, can I work without DLL-s(libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll)?

Comment: @evilone "with Synapse, can I work without DLL" - No. It's designed to work *with* OpenSSL.

Comment: Which library works without DLL-s? Only SecureBlackBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "EOF" error suggests you are connnecting to a server that is not actually using SSL to begin with, or the SSL data may be corrupted.

Besides that, why are you including explicit '&' characters between your post data parameters?  Don't do that, Indy will just encode them and send its own '&' characters.  Also, consider using TMemoryStream instead of TStringStream to ensure IXMLDocumect.LoadFromStream() is loading the server's original raw XML data as-is, and not an altered version that the RTL/VCL produces due to Unicode handling (TStringStream is TEncoding-enabled).

**Edit:** Given the URL you provided, an example of calling verifyUser() would look like this:

```
const
  ERPLYAccountCode = '...';

function verifyUser(const user, pass: string; const sessionLength: Integer = 3600): IXMLDocument;
var
  sPostData: TStringList;
  sHttpSocket: TIdHTTP;
  sshSocketHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  resStream: TMemoryStream;
  xDoc: IXMLDocument;
begin
  Result := nil;
  try
    resStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      sPostData := TStringList.Create;
      try
        sPostData.Add('clientCode=' + ERPLYAccountCode);
        sPostData.Add('request=verifyUser');
        sPostData.Add('version=1.0');
        sPostData.Add('responseType=XML');
        sPostData.Add('responseMode=normal');
        sPostData.Add('username=' + user);
        sPostData.Add('password=' + pass);
        sPostData.Add('sessionLength=' + IntToStr(sessionLength));
        sHttpSocket := TIdHTTP.Create;
        try
          sshSocketHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(sHttpSocket);
          sHttpSocket.IOHandler := sshSocketHandler;
          sHttpSocket.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
          sHttpSocket.Post('https://www.erply.net/api/', sPostData, resStream);
        finally
          sHttpSocket.Free;
        end;
      finally
        sPostData.Free;
      end;
      resStream.Position := 0;
      xDoc := CreateXMLDoc;
      xDoc.LoadFromStream(resStream);
      Result := xDoc;
    finally
      resStream.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      TCommon.ErrorLog('errorLog.txt', DateTimeToStr(Now) + ' ' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The actual URL is https://www.erply.net/api/. 

This request method send parameters request=verifyUser, clientCode=eng, username=demo, password=demouser, responseType=XML and version=1.0

But I use other methods as well. GetProducts(), GetEmployees() and so on. But they all use this SendRequest() method.

You can view this API reference here http://www.inventoryapi.com/?id=347&page=getting-started#sending_request

Comment: I marked that as an answer, but haven't got total answer yet. But it's hundred percent better answer than Eugene's was.

Comment: That's not an answer at all -- connection fails 50% of times, and you say nothing more than "is not actually using SSL to begin with, or the SSL data may be corrupted", which makes no sense in context of the question. Obviously the problem is in OpenSSL.

Comment: The only way to diagnose the real problem is to use a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, to make sure the SSL data is accurate.